# Estimate the order of the integral for small enough $\epsilon$

Tags: analysis, improper-integrals

The integral is :
$$I(\epsilon)=\int_0^1 \frac{dt}{\epsilon+e^{-1/t}}$$
I need to find the order of $\epsilon$ when $\epsilon\to 0$, such as : $\lim_{\epsilon\to0} \epsilon I(\epsilon)=C$, where C is non-zero.

I have tried the two following ways:

> **First try:** Using the change of variable $t=\frac{1}{x}$, we have:
> $$\int_0^1 \frac{dt}{\epsilon+e^{-1/t}} =\int_1^{+\infty}\frac{1}{\epsilon+e^{-x}}\cdot \frac{1}{x^2}\, dx\,.$$
> Since $0<e^{-x}<1$, for any $x\in(1,+\infty)$, we obtain:
> $$\frac{1}{\epsilon+1} \int_1^{+\infty} \frac{1}{x^2}\, dx \leq \int_1^{+\infty}\frac{1}{\epsilon+e^{-x}}\cdot \frac{1}{x^2}\, dx \leq \frac{1}{\epsilon} \int_1^{+\infty} \frac{1}{x^2}\, dx .$$
> From this result, we only know the upper bound is $O(\frac{1}{\epsilon})$ ; for the lower bound we have no idea.

> **Second try:** By using integration by parts, we get:
> $$\begin{aligned}
> \int_0^1 \frac{dt}{\epsilon+e^{-1/t}} &= \int_0^1 \frac{e^{\frac{1}{t}}}{\epsilon e^{\frac{1}{t}} +1}\,dt \\&=-\left[\frac{1}{\epsilon}\ln(\epsilon e^{\frac{1}{t}} +1)t^2\right]_{t=0}^1+ \frac{2}{\epsilon} \int_0^1 t \ln(\epsilon e^{\frac{1}{t}} +1)\,dt\\&= -\frac{1}{\epsilon}\ln(\epsilon e +1) + \frac{2}{\epsilon} \int_0^1 t \ln(\epsilon e^{\frac{1}{t}} +1)\,dt\,.
> \end{aligned}$$ I have no idea how to continue.

I’m looking forward to your help, thanks!

Comment: By definition, $f(x)\in O(g(x))$ if $f(x)/g(x)$ remains bounded. Now, denote $I(\varepsilon)$ to be your integral. From your first try, you get that $\varepsilon I(\varepsilon)$ is between $\varepsilon/(1+\varepsilon)$ and $1$, using $\int\frac{dx}{x^2}=1$. This means that you indeed have $I(\varepsilon)\in O(1/\varepsilon)$.

Comment: But $\epsilon/(1+\epsilon)\to 0$ as $\epsilon \to 0$, actually I want to find the same order between $I(\epsilon)$ and some form of $\epsilon$, which means the limit is finite and nonzero.

Comment: This still yields a $O(1/\varepsilon)$. Are you looking for a $\Theta$ instead ?

Comment: I’m sorry, what does $\Theta$ mean? What I want is like $\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}I(\epsilon)/\epsilon^{\alpha} = a$, and $a\neq 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $R = -\log \epsilon$ and note that $R \to \infty$ as $\epsilon \to 0^+$. Then by the substitution $x = Ru$,

$$ I(\epsilon)
= \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{e^{R}}{1 + e^{-(x-R)}} \, \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x^2}
= \frac{e^{R}}{R} \int_{\frac{1}{R}}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1 + e^{-R(u-1)}} \, \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{u^2}. $$

Now it is not hard to check that

$$ \lim_{R\to\infty} \int_{\frac{1}{R}}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1 + e^{-R(u-1)}} \, \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{u^2}
= \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{u^2}
= 1, $$

and so, we get the following asymptotic equivalence:

$$ I(\epsilon) \sim \frac{e^R}{R} = \frac{1}{\epsilon \log(1/\epsilon)} \quad \text{as} \quad \epsilon \to 0^+.$$

Indeed, the following is the graph of $\epsilon I(\epsilon) \log(1/\epsilon)$ over $(0, 1)$:

[image: Graph of the ratio]

Comment: Thank you very much!